# Get the Date Difference Between two dates excluding fridays in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have the following two dates :**

```
startDate = '2017-04-04'  and  endDate = '2017-04-12'
```

I would like to find the total count of days between these two dates excluding `'Fridays'` using SQL Server.

**Any Help from the SQL Server Experts will be highly appreciated!! Thanks in Advance!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`DATENAME`** to check for `'Friday'` do this, something like this :

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME
SET @startDate = '2017-04-04'
SET @endDate = '2017-04-12'

Declare @count int
set @count=0

    while @startDate < @endDate
    Begin
        IF DATENAME(dw, @startDate) <> 'Friday'
            SET @count = @count + 1
        SET @startDate = DateAdd(d, 1, @startDate)
    END
select @count
```

This will result in :

```
7
```

Comment: Its coming 8. What should have been the answer according to you ?

Comment: It should be 7 as there is a Friday between them..Check With it....SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2017-04-04','2017-04-12') AS DiffDate..This is returning 8..Your code should return 7..

Comment: datediff checks boundaries that you need to cross for reachind dates in either direction.

Comment: But its not solving my problem!! Will it be possible what  am i expecting..??

Comment: Still not working as expected!! Check with it... SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2017-04-04','2017-04-22') AS DiffDate...This returning 18  and Your code should return 15 as there are 3 fridays between them but your code returning 16

Comment: No!! Now check with SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2017-04-04','2017-04-12') AS DiffDate ..

Comment: Interesting, there is some boundary condition. Will try to find solution to that.

Comment: Hey, check the edit. I think this new solution covers all edge cases. Let me know

Comment: Yes!! Finally You are Successful!! Congrats!!

Comment: This was interesting. Actually, weeks in sql server are counted from 1-7 and not by any seven days.

Answer (score 0):

just add below clause to your query

```
select count(*) from table
where startDate >= '2017-01-12' and endDate <= '2017-04-27' 
and datename(WEEKDAY,startdate))<>'Friday'
```

Comment: For more understandable, Please write the whole query with the given dates in question.

Comment: @TanvirArjel:see updated,but not sure on why you have two dates and how it could effect the result